# BizFX restrict user access to specific shop or catalog

Tags: sitecore-commerce

Is there a way to restrict a user access to a specific shop or catalog in BizFX UI so that the user that owns a specific set of products can only manage it but not the other products?

Comment: It's not possible at this moment. Maybe will be available in future releases